# Extract element with no class attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to navigate to an html element of a particular type.
However, there are many such elements of that type on the page, with many different classes.

I need one which **does not have any class attribute**.

Should I look for one with `class == ''`, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use

```
soup.findAll(attrs={'class': None})
```

Quoting from docs:

> You can use attrs if you need to put restrictions on attributes whose names are Python reserved words, like class, for, or import; or attributes whose names are non-keyword arguments to the Beautiful Soup search methods: name, recursive, limit, text, or attrs itself.

Answer (score 17):

As of [Beautiful Soup version 4.1.2](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class), you can use the [`class_` keyword argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments).

To select an element without a class attribute, you can just specify `None`:

```
soup.find_all(class_=None)
```

Alternatively, specifying `False` also works:

```
soup.find_all(class_=False)
```